# Mock static void method with params using mockito and Junit5

Tags: java, static, mocking, mockito, junit5

I am trying to mock a static void method that take a parameter `SMTPTools.send(Message)`

My deps:

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
      <version>5.7.0</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
      <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
      <version>3.6.0</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
      <artifactId>mockito-inline</artifactId>
      <version>3.6.0</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
      <artifactId>mockito-junit-jupiter</artifactId>
      <version>3.6.0</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

T try:

```
    try (MockedStatic<SMTPTools> smtpToolsMocked = Mockito.mockStatic(SMTPTools.class)) {
      smtpToolsMocked.when((msg) -> SMTPTools.send(msg)).thenAnswer((Answer<Void>) invocation -> null);
    }
```

But it's not even compiling cause

> The method when(MockedStatic.Verification) in the type MockedStatic is not applicable for the arguments (( msg) -> {})

But I understand why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok it works with:

```
  @Test
  public void staticTest() throws Exception {
    try (MockedStatic<SMTPTools> smtpToolsMocked = Mockito.mockStatic(SMTPTools.class)) {
      Message msg = null;
      smtpToolsMocked.when((msg) -> SMTPTools.send(msg)).thenAnswer((Answer<Void>) invocation -> null);
      SMTPTools.send(msg);
      smtpToolsMocked.verify(Mockito.times(1), () -> SMTPTools.send(msg));
    }
  }
```